# is output=false needed for all cfc method written in CFML?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Is `output="false"` needed for all cfc method written in CFML? or it'd be okay as long as the outer most caller function has `output="false"`?

What if we don't add `output="false"` on any CFC methods, but we make sure the top-most caller is inside a `<cfsilent>` block? is that okay?

Is `output="false"` solely for suppressing whitespace?  I recall years ago CFer's said having `output="false"` helps with preventing memory leak: myth or fact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, in Adobe ColdFusion, `output="false"` at the component level does not affect each individual function, just the constructor area. This may not even matter because I can't think of a way to output anything from the constructor, and indeed, even changing to `output="true"` seems to make no difference.

I have now (thanks to you, Henry) experimented with chaining functions with `output="false"`, and your suspicions are right - a calling function with `output="false"` will suppress the output from any function it calls. This was in Adobe ColdFusion 9.0.1.

Adding a `cfsilent` around the initialization of a component will mute output from the component without an `output="false"`, but again I don't think that does anything. Putting  around a function call will mute any output from anything it calls.

`output="false"` is solely for whitespace suppression. You could argue that adding whitespace to the output buffer would increase memory usage, per request, but I wouldn't really call it a leak - perhaps if you have tens of thousands of component/function calls, it could cause trouble.

`Output="true"` does have a different effect, treating a function as if it has `<cfoutput>` tags wrapped around it, and evaluating any `#` dynamic things automatically.

Comment: Somehow misleading implementation of the attribute, in my opinion. `whitespace='false'` should have been used instead... and `output='false'` being the default case.